# Cannot connect to Kubernetes NodePort Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a running pod that was created with the following `pod-definition.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: microservice-one-pod-name
    labels:
        app: microservice-one-app-label
        type: front-end
spec:
    containers:
    - name: microservice-one
      image: vismarkjuarez1994/microserviceone
      ports:
      - containerPort: 2019
```

I then created a Service using the following `service-definition.yaml`:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: microserviceone-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 30008
      targetPort: 2019
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: microservice-one-app-label
  type: NodePort
```

I then ran `kubectl describe node minikube` to find the Node IP I should be connecting to -- which yielded:

```sh
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.49.2
  Hostname:    minikube
```

But I get no response when I run the following curl command:

```sh
curl 192.168.49.2:30008
```

The request also times out when I try to access `192.168.49.2:30008` from a browser.

The pod logs show that the container is up and running. Why can't I access my Service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access your service at the `port` parameter which is the internal port at which the service will be exposed, even when using `NodePort` type.

The parameter you were searching is called `nodePort`, which can optionally be specified together with `port` and `targetPort`. Quoting the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport):

> By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will
> allocate a port from a range (default: `30000-32767`)

Since you didn't specify the `nodePort`, one in the range was automatically picked up. You can check which one by:

```
kubectl get svc -owide
```

And then access your service externally at that port.

As an alternative, you can change your service definition to be something like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: microserviceone-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 30008
      targetPort: 2019
      nodePort: 30008
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: microservice-one-app-label
  type: NodePort
```

But take in mind that you may need to delete your service and create it again in order to change the `nodePort` allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I've changed my service definition to match your suggestion, but I still get no response when running `curl 192.168.49.2:30008`

Comment: Do you still have problems? As I see you accepted the answer as correct

Comment: Your solution was correct -- I simply had to tunnel into Minikube in order to access. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed the Port in your service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: microservice-one-pod-name
    labels:
        app: microservice-one-app-label
        type: front-end
spec:
    containers:
    - name: microservice-one
      image: vismarkjuarez1994/microserviceone
      ports:
      - containerPort: 2019
```

and your service should be like this:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: microserviceone-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 2019
      targetPort: 2019
      nodePort: 30008
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: microservice-one-app-label
  type: NodePort
```

You can access to your app after enabling the Minikube ingress if you want trying Ingress with Minikube.

```sh
minikube addons enable ingress
```